Display UTC time in local time with timezone
I'm attempting to display some UTC time in ISO format (2024-09-05T00:00:00), as local time (2024-09-05T09:00:00+0900). It's been challenging to achieve this in an elegant way, ideally only using native Python libraries.
To get a date-time string I do
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> time.tzname
('JST', 'JST')
>>> utc_time = "2024-09-05T00:00:00"
>>> utc_dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(utc_time)
>>> utc_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2024-09-05T00:00:00'

However, this is not UTC time! This is localized:
>>> utc_dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Tokyo")).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2024-09-05T00:00:00+0900'

My expectation was that fromisoformat would assume UTC when timezone information was not provided, meaning that the above would also have 9 hours added after the astimezone operation (2024-09-05T09:00:00+0900). Instead it remains the same.
Buy why? This is not intuitive! If timezone is not provided then one would most probably assume UTC IMO. How to fix this in an elegant way? The best I could come up with is to add a Z to my input:
>>> utc_time = "2024-09-05T01:09:11" + "Z"
>>> utc_dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(utc_time)
>>> utc_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2024-09-05T00:00:00+0000'
>>> utc_dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Tokyo")).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2024-09-05T09:00:00+0900'

This is what I wanted, but feels like a hack... is there a better/elegant way to do this?

And then there's this:
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(utc_time).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Asia/Tokyo")).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'2024-09-05T00:00:00+0919'



I think this is a reasonable complaint. I think you can add the tz info to your original date time with utc_dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(utc_time).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) and then the regular conversion should work. This is mentioned with an example in the docs

@Mark I like that solution, it looks more elegant than adding an element to my input. So my full solution would be utc_dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(utc_time).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"). Thanks.

There is no timezone in the initial input, so the resulting datetime is naïve. Python will not implicitly assume anything (unless it does, there are some pitfalls in the API, but not in this case). If the input has no timezone, then it doesn't, end of story. Thus you can't convert it to any other timezone, as that makes no sense.

As for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741833/476

@deceze Thank you for the explanation and . I assumed that when no timezone is defined then a default one was assumed (most probably zero), as time is necessarily linked to a zone. I did not know about the Python's naïve time interpretation, which was the confusing part... but I guess there's a reason for it. Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/2867/

@Solenoid note that the issue described in the Q&A linked by deceze is specific to the pytz library, so implementation-specific essentially. Considering the xkcd strip, I think a lot of the "scary" parts of datetime/timezones in computer programming stem from specific implementations - trust me, I roll my own datetime ^^

Here's a way:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

utc_time = "2024-09-05T00:00:00"

# to datetime.
# since your input does not specify a UTC offset, the datetime object does not 
# know that it's supposed to be UTC. It is "naive"; tzinfo is None.
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(utc_time)
print(dt, dt.tzinfo)
# 2024-09-05 00:00:00 None

# make it a UTC datetime.
dt_utc = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(dt_utc)
# 2024-09-05 00:00:00+00:00

# my local time:
print(dt_utc.astimezone(None))
# 2024-09-05 02:00:00+02:00

# a specific time zone:
print(dt_utc.astimezone(ZoneInfo("Asia/Tokyo")))
# 2024-09-05 09:00:00+09:00

Some additional notes.

pytz is deprecated since Python 3.9 - we have zoneinfo in the standard lib
if you have to use pytz, make sure to localize, don't replace a tzinfo!
astimezone converts to a time zone, replace (or localize) sets a time zone
see also Display the time in a different time zone, How to convert local time string to UTC?

